# How can I specify a context for NodeJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I am using the following script to compile a string as a module. How can I specify a context for this module, so that `myGlobal` is available in the code?

```js
const myGlobal = "Hello";

function compile(src) {
  var m = new module.constructor;
  m._compile(src, '');
  return m.exports;
}

(async()=> {
    const code = `
      module.exports = async () => {
        return myGlobal;
      }
    `;
    const result = await compile(code)()
    console.log(result)
})();

// ReferenceError: myGlobal is not defined
```

Comment: There is no offical documentation about that. Is there a reason why you dont use the `vm` module instead?

Comment: The module is compiled with the normal globals. Your problem appears to be that `myGlobal` is not a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments, which lead me to getting `vm` to work:

```js
const vm = require('node:vm');

(async()=> {
    const code = `
    const got = require('got');
    module.exports = async (data) => {
        return myGlobal + ' ' + data;
    }
    `;

    const context = { myGlobal: 'Hello', module: {}, require  }
    vm.createContext(context);
    const script = new vm.Script(code)

    const result = await script.runInContext(context)('John');
    console.log(result)
})();

// Hello John
```